# ArangoDB Graph Viewer Options: Label using more than one attribute

Tags: database, graph, graphics, nosql, arangodb

In Arango's Game of Thrones example dataset, they show a graph view where character nodes are labeled with two attributes: name and surname. How is this done?

[Arango graph viewer example with Game of Thrones character data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srjao.png)

The [help](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Programs/WebInterface/Graphs.html) doesn't explain it.

> Graph Viewer Options
>   Nodes Options Menu:
>   Label (string): Nodes will be
>   labeled by this attribute. If node attribute is not found, no label will be displayed.

That makes it sound like only a single attribute can be used, yet their example shows the use of two attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily it's ArangoDB open source, so it's possible to achieve it and quite easily

[image]

here's [quick and dirty commit adding such a functionality](https://github.com/pavelsevcik/arangodb/commit/720aa96731f121de031b8d5f54f3c8ad1c9e6ccb)

**to test it, not deploying it into production as it can cause unexpected security issues**

clone on linux `https://github.com/pavelsevcik/arangodb`, cd into it, switch branch to `feature/graph-viewer-config-labels--quick-and-dirty` and run

```
cd js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP
npm install
npm run grunt
mv node_modules ..
zip -r ../app.zip .
mv .. /node_modules .
```

then deploy created `js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/app.zip` via `services` > `add service` > `upload` > set mount point to `/aardvark`

then change in url `_admin/aardvark` to `aardvark` and test it

here's [Feature Request: Support of multiple attributes for displaying labels in Graph Viewer](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/7772)

Answer (score 1):

The Graph Viewer does not support multiple attributes for displaying labels.

I took a screenshot of the graph without any labels and edited it in Paint.NET, that's the whole secret. This was for full control about the font face, size and placement. This combination was the easiest way to do it when I wrote the [AQL tutorial](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Tutorial/).

Feel free to open a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/new) nonetheless.